# Combination Q : How many combinations of $5$ cards contain only diamonds?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

Question 1a) How many possible combinations of $5$ card poker hands are there?

Answer : $\binom{52}5$ - basically the combination formula : $$\frac{N!}{(N-r)!r!}$$
(this is correct because we did it in class)

I need help on this question : How many combinations of $5$ cards contain only diamonds?

My Answer : $\binom{52}5 - \left[\binom{52}{13}+\binom{52}{13}+\binom{52}{13}\right]$

Is it correct? If not, what is the correct answer?

Comment: That's a negative number you've got there!

Comment: Use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for future questions.

Answer (score 3):

Why choose from 52 cards? You are asked to find the number of 5 card hands from a single suit i.e from 13 cards. Use the same formula as in (1) such that you have $C(13,5)$.

Answer (score 0):

The number of ways to choose 5 cards from the 13 cards which are diamonds is ${13 \choose 5}$.

If you want to count the size of the complement set and subtract off from ${52 \choose 5}$, then you need to find the number of five card poker hands which contain one or more cards of another suite.  The expression you are subtracting off is not this value.